# Change background color of div on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to change to background color of a div class every time the window reloads.
I've used this code to change the background color of the body on refresh:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //Enter list of bgcolors:
var bgcolorlist=new Array("silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")

document.body.style.background=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]
// -->
</script>
```

But I'm looking to change the background color of '.three' so every div with the class 'three' will have a different background color every time the window reloads (choosing from an array of colors).
Can't seem to figure out how to do this, is it at all possible?

Comment: Please don't use the array constructor like you do: instead of writing `new Array()`, use the literal notation: `[]`. A lot shorter _and_ more predictable. Same goes for objects: use `{}` instead of `new Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var bgcolorlist=new Array("silver", "#BAF3C3", "#c3baf3")

$(".three").css("background-color",bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the bg-colour *has* to be changed, you could use `localStorage` to check what the bg was prior to the page being reloaded:

```
var colours = ['#F00','#0F0'];//my eyes!
var currentColour = +(localStorage.previousBGColour || -1)+1;
currentColour = currentColour >= colours.length ? 0 : currentColour;//if index is not set reset to colour at index 0
document.getElementById('theDiv').style.backgroundColor = colours[currentColour];
localStorage.previousBGColour =  currentColour;//store colour that's currently in use
```

Note that not all browsers support `localStorage`: some people are still using old, crummy IE8, for example.

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    (function()
    {//this IIFE is optional, but is just a lot tidier (no vars cluttering the rest of the script)
        var colours = ['#F00','#0F0'],
        currentColour = +(localStorage.previousBGColour || -1) + 1;
        $('#theDiv').css({backgroundColor:colours[currentColour]});
        localStorage.previousBGColour = currentColour;
    }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.three').css('background-color',bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bgcolorlist = ['silver', '#BAF3C3', '#C3BAF3'];

$(function() {
    $('.three').css({
        background: bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]
    });
});
```

Every time the page loads, this picks a random colour from the list and sets it on the body's css.

Answer (score 0):

By using pure JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".three");
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         arr[i].style.background = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)]
    }
}
```

This will give all divs with class three random colors. If you want all to be same, just cache the math.random to a variable