# Random color generated upon refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, colors

I was wondering if I can get help in making my website change to a random color scheme (ex. replace blue background with a red and yellow hovers with a grey) upon refresh of the page. Here is the code (http://jsbin.com/yudiwaza/1/edit?html,css,js,output). I've been googling but can't seem to get the solutions I found to work with my site. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: your link doesn't seem to work, and you should include code directly in your question too

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13625581/3518203. it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not apply random colors, they will look ugly -- define your colors yourself.

The best way to do this is apply a random class on body tag and use CSS to change colors. for example i am changing background color in demo but you can change any thing control your entire layout styles.

### **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yudiwaza/2/edit)**

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var themeClassName = "theme_"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $('body').addClass(themeClassName);
});
```

**Css:**

```
.theme_1{
    background: #f00;
}
.theme_2{
    background: #0f0;
}
.theme_3{
    background: #00f;
}
.theme_4{
    background: #000;
}
.theme_ .... // till 10 different classes
```

If the number of themes you want is less or more then 10 then change this value:

```
(Math.random() * 10 <--This value from the above code
```